# Sum of Geometric series from a and r

Tags: sequences-and-series

How does one compute the no. of terms $n$  in a geometric series given the first term $a$, the ratio $r$, the sum of the series $s$.

The answer found corresponds to $n = \dfrac{\log\left(1+\frac{s(1-r)}{a}\right)}{\log r}\quad$ (for $r<1$)

Does this solution have any limitation in finding n ? or what is the error in finding actual $n$ and $n$ computed from the solution ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Let $ r \ne 1$. Then $s=a+ar+...+ar^{n-1}$. This gives

$s=a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ or

$r^n=1-\frac{s(1-r)}{a}$. It follows:

$n \log r=\log(1-\frac{s(1-r)}{a})$.

For $r=1$ we have $s=na$, or $n=s/a$.